# Filezilla not updating files

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I made a modification in a php file and uploaded it via Filezilla. It always worked fine for me, even if sometimes it would not upload immediately. This time, however, it's not working anymore in any way. I upload the file with the same name and it looks like it overwrites the old one, but the size of the file doesn't change. When I open the site on the browser (I've been testing in Chrome and Firefox and already cleaned their caches many times since then, and still nothing happens) and look at the source code, it shows the new code with the modification, but even so the site is still the same old one. When I open the file directly from Filezilla it also shows the modified file, but the file size doesn't change. It started yesterday, before the upgrading to version 3.7.3. It's updated now, but the files are still not being updated. I also tried renaming the file, deleting it from the ftp and uploading again, uploading it to another folder and then moving it to the root, but nothing happens. Any idea of what can be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it was a problem with the permissions with the host. I contacted them and the issue was solved.